# Send JSON Data From JavaScript to a Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, getparameter

... I am experiencing an anomaly that I do not understand why.
The scenario is as follows:

1.- From JSP, using JS, I send data in JSON format to a servlet.

```
  JSON:  "{'ORDER': '1', 'DATE': '06-01-2018', 'TIME': '07:06:51', 'BOUCHER': '208896.0', 'LIC' : 'HSGR30', 'QTY': '0.0'} "
```

2.- I capture the data, with the getParameter utility, on a String type variable.

3.- I pass the variable to the JSONObject utility, and it does not process it since there are two "" (**two double quotes**) in that variable, and debugging the class (JSONObject) throws an exception because the first character of the string is not "{" ... which is logical.

4.- Now, if I take the complete stream and paste it in the call:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject ("{'ORDER': '1', 'DATE': '06-01-2018', 'TIME': '07:06:51', 'BOUCHER': '208896.0' , 'LIC': 'HSGR30', 'QTY': '0.0'} ")
```

It processes it correctly and I get the object with its associated properties and values.

I was considering that the JSON format I send from JS is not valid???. But I can't find the cause of why???

The problem is that I don't understand why two double quotes appear.

If you can give me a hand with this,

thank you very much !!!

Comment: Strings in JSON are supposed to use double quotes, e.g. `"ORDER": "1"` instead of `'ORDER': '1'`. Other than that, your JSON looks valid, although you may want to store numbers such as `QTY` as numbers rather than strings, e.g. drop the quotes, for more efficiency.

Comment: You can use a JSON validator - for example [this one](https://jsonlint.com/). You will see the point made by EricReed about `"` vs `'`.

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes: `"` instead of single quotes: `'` and use `\` before each doublquote to escape the characters.

E.g:

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject ("{\"ORDER\": \"1\",\"DATE\": \"06-01-2018\",\"TIME\": \"07: 06: 51\",\"BOUCHER\": \"208896.0\",\"LIC\": \"HSGR30\",\"QTY\": \"0.0\"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Very grateful for your prompt replies.

I found the problem, in the js code I was doing **JSON.stringify()**. I remove it and everything is fine.

I just need to rethink how to send, from js, package JSON formatted records.

It was not clear how **JSONObject** handles the string it receives.

I guess I'll have to rethink an array of JSON objects and then send it. Perhaps, by receiving array object type, it will understand that it is a batch of records.

Thanks again